# Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Server) Server was unable to process request, Parameter name: s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap-client

We have a ROR application where we are using soap api's.
To integrate the soap api's i am using `Savon Gem` version 2.0

In `GemFile`
`gem 'savon', '~> 2.0'`

I am getting error for SOAP API Which I am using to POST the Data into database I'm Confused whether the error is from my side or API side.

- first create a connection: `client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: 'some wsdl url')`
- To get the method list: `client.operations`
- And to call the method: `client.call(:method_name, message: {parameters})`

When i hit this i got one error message
Message: `Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Server) Server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s`

[here](http://savonrb.com/version2/client.html) is the doc which i am referring for the soap api integration.

checked some stack overflow questions but no luck.
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just some quick checks, are you sure that your request is hitting the intended server? and, that you have your parameters structured properly? If you make a request using another SOAP api client does it work?

Comment: @MichaelGorman yes it's hitting the server, because if it is not, then it will not return the methods name, i guess. but good point weather it's hitting the server or not, i will check again and let you know

Comment: I had one issue with Savon/SOAP a couple weeks back, where the server I was connecting to, had their WSDL set to redirect me to an IP address that I didn't have access to.  This meant that the WSDL request `client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: 'some wsdl url')` worked, and I could get the`client.operations` but the `client.call` was wasn't making it.

Comment: Another test you can do is run `build_request`, instead of `call` to see if the request you are making is being structured in the expected format